# Display variant title on cart page

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

On the cart page, I currently display items that have been added to the cart with:

```
{{ lineItem.description }}
```

What I want to do, rather than displaying the product name and variant title as one, is to split them. So that I can display the variant title separately from the product name.

What is the correct model for this?

Comment: `lineItem.purchasable.title` is the variant title, `lineItem.purchasable.product.title` is the product title.

Answer (score 2):

`lineItem.purchasable.title` is the variant title, `lineItem.purchasable.product.title` is the product title.